# Ember leaflet on not showing, on changing hidden property it displays but not properly

Tags: ember.js, leaflet, hybrid-mobile-app

I am using Ember-leaflet for my ember application. I followed every step from installation to usage but somehow it is not showing anything.
I inspected the elements and found property `overflow:hidden`. I changed to `overflow:visible` then map was showing but on zooming in and out, image expands awkwardly.

I am using in my template.hbs

`{{#leaflet-map lat=lat lng=lng zoom=zoom}}
  {{tile-layer url="http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"}}
{{/leaflet-map}}`

and in my template.js

`export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  lat: 45.519743,
  lng: -122.680522,
  zoom: 10
});`
  reference used from http://www.ember-leaflet.com . Do I required to import or include any CSS or JS file. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this helped me

```
.leaflet-container{
   height:300px;
}
```

Raised issue and got the reply:
https://github.com/miguelcobain/ember-leaflet/issues/139